# Flex 4 - Using .pfm/.pfb fonts

Tags: apache-flex, fonts, embed, flash-builder

I just switched to Flash Builder 4 & Flex 4 SDK, and it seems it's no longer possible to use a .pfm/.pfb font, either by embedding it or using it as a system font.

I keep getting error messages, and Google can't find anybody having the same issue.

I tried several methods:
- copy/pasting the [Embed] statement which was working using Flex 3 SDK
- installing the font and then try to simply call it by its name in a CSS declaration without embedding it ; seems to work for every .ttf and .otf system fonts, but not for .pfm/.pfm ones
- using a Flash-generated swf which embeds the font

So far none of these seems to work.

Has anybody got an idea on how to achieve this?
I actually don't care using a system font without embedding it as long as it works.

I'll be really grateful if somebody could help me on this, I'm totally stuck and cannot use another font instead.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting following errror:

Error: exception during transcoding:  Unable to transcode ../path/to/font.pfb

I had to add embedAsCFF=false and it works now!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look into this document.. .

http://blogs.adobe.com/flexdoc/fonts.pdf

Comment: I already read this document, and it says that the only way is to use Flash CS to generate a swf embedding the font.
It works well with ttf or otf fonts, but I can't get it to work with pfm/pfb ones =/